# Attaching to Elixir application fails to provide prompt

Tags: elixir, exrm

I am able to attach to an Elixir application that is deployed, but I can't seem to give it any commands (no IEX prompt). It seems like a form-feed character is getting in the way, this is my prompt after attaching:

```
Attaching to /var/www/tmp/erl_pipes/avant_garden/erlang.pipe.1 (^D to exit)

^L
```

The application works (it's a web application, and I can access pages from the browser served by it). But I can't get the console.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: The issue is not solved yet: https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/315

Comment: FWIW, I downgraded to exrm 1.0.2 from 1.0.6 which seems to resolve the issue for now.